# Graphics plotting delay in Real time tracking system User Interface (using c# winform application)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am developing a real-time localization tracking system UI using  winform application (C#). I am experiencing little delay in plotting graphics (of about 3 to 4 seconds) in the UI visualization panel. And I really don't understand why this is happenning? is this because of communication delays between the server and the client?

The client sends information to the server at the rate of 100 milliseconds and with this rate the client sends objects position information to the server (the server is implemented as a winform application (C#)).

On the server the data receiving thread started under form_load event handler. The data receiving thread receives the objects position information from the Client, and these object position graphics display on panel Control. The graphics plotting done under panel paint event handler.  I use the UDP protocol for communication between the server and the client.

Both client and server programs are operated on different systems.

Can anyone tell me why this delay occurs?
I am sharing the snippet of my code

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form // server program for 3 objects tracking display
   {
    Pen P;
    Rectangle r1, r2;
    Image i1;
    Double t1x, t1y, t2x, t2y, t3x, t3y;
    Boolean draw1 = false;
    Graphics g;

    Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch(); // time computation of receiver thread
    TimeSpan tstart, tstop;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        P = new Pen(Color.LightCyan, 3);
        r1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 410, 300); // SIZE OF THE RECTANGLE STARTING FROM (0,0) OF THE IMAGE
        i1 = new Bitmap("Childr.png");
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread Data_Read1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(data_read1));
        Data_Read1.Start();

        typeof(Panel).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered",
        BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null, panel1, new object[] { true });
    }
    public void data_read1()
    {
        UdpClient UdpServer = new UdpClient(1001);
        IPEndPoint Sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        while (true)
        {
            Byte[] data1 = UdpServer.Receive(ref Sender);
            String line1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data1);
            var part = line1.Split('\t');

            tstart = time.Elapsed;
            time.Start();
            if (Double.Parse(part[0]) == 1)
            {
                t1x = (Double.Parse(part[1]) / 0.0347) + 96;
                t1y = (Double.Parse(part[2]) / 0.0335) + 362;
            }
            if (Double.Parse(part[0]) == 2)
            {
                t2x = (Double.Parse(part[1]) / 0.0347) + 96;
                t2y = (Double.Parse(part[2]) / 0.0335) + 362;
            }
            if (Double.Parse(part[0]) == 3)
            {
                t3x = (Double.Parse(part[1]) / 0.0347) + 96;
                t3y = (Double.Parse(part[2]) / 0.0335) + 362;
            }

            draw1 = true;
            panel1.Invoke(new Action(() => { panel1.Invalidate(); }));

            time.Stop();
            tstop = time.Elapsed;

            double dt = (Math.Round(tstop.TotalMilliseconds, 2) - Math.Round(tstart.TotalMilliseconds, 2));
            listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { listBox1.Items.Add(Math.Round(dt, 2)); }));
        }
    }
    private void panel1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = e.Graphics;
        if (draw1 == true)
        {
            g.DrawImage(i1, Convert.ToInt32(t1y), Convert.ToInt32(t1x), 18, 21);
            g.DrawImage(i1, Convert.ToInt32(t2y), Convert.ToInt32(t2x), 18, 21);
            g.DrawImage(i1, Convert.ToInt32(t3y), Convert.ToInt32(t3x), 18, 21);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell if the delay is only at the start or stays..?

Comment: its not from the start its stay in the end